# Adding multiple turtle values in a list on NETLOGO to then calculate the variance

Tags: netlogo, variance

I am calculating the consumption rate of each turtle in the model. I then want to create a list of each turtle's consumption rate value so I can then calculate the variance of it. I can not figure out how to add those values into my list so that I can calculate the variance, any help? Here is my code so far:

```
ask turtles
[ set consumption-rate ( [ quality ] of patch-here ) / ( strength-of-competition * count turtles-here )]

show variance [ ]
```

Answer (score 2):

NetLogo makes this kind of thing *very* easy. It's just:

```
show variance [ consumption-rate ] of turtles
```

The [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) primitive isn't just for accessing the variables of individual agents: it also works with agentsets, in which case it constructs a list of the results, which is exactly what you need here.